# logical operators replacing if statements

Tags: python, logical-operators, pep8

Are the following uses of logical expressions Pythonic / pep8 compliant?

1. This:

   ```
   x = a or b
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   if not a:
       x = b
   else:
       x = a
   ```
2. This:

   ```
   x = a and b
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   if not a:
       x = a
   else:
       x = b
   ```
3. (The curve-ball?) This:

   ```
   x = x or y
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   if not x:
       x = y
   ```

Comment: I don't think PEP8 specifies this sort of thing. My opinion: The second versions are much more readable and therefore preferable. Don't make me think.

Comment: 1 and 3 are straightforward and commonly used (although I'm not sure about 3), but 2 took me a few seconds to read, so I probably wouldn't use it.

Comment: Even if they're correct, they're very hard to comprehend IMHO. Also, how often is `not a` really what you want (rather than, for example, `a is None`)?

Comment: "Readability counts". Irregardless of how easy any of them are to read for relatively experienced Python programmers, I think they could confuse anyone coming from a language where logical operators return booleans.

Comment: #1 and #3 are identical and somewhat widely used. I've never seen #2 used. The need for those is diminished since the introduction of the ternary `.. if .. else ..`.

Comment: If 1 and 2 were unpythonic, `and` and `or` would have boolean results, since this is the only application of their current behavior

Comment: @PavelAnossov For #2 consider a boolean xml attribute:  `attr = node.hasAttr('y') and node.getAttr('y') == 'True'`

Comment: @Scruffy: okay, everyone I know would write it as `attr = False; if node.hasAttr('y'): attr = node.getAttr('y')`. But it feels weird for `False` to signify absence. So it would be `attr = None`.

Comment: @Scruffy: `node.get('y', False)` is much more straightforward.

Comment: @Blender I'm using the native xml.dom and I don't think it supports that dict type get... please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Scruffy: lxml and `xml.etree` both use it. I'm not too sure about other parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C and Java, Python's logical operators don't return booleans. I can't imagine another use case for that language feature besides the one in your question, so unless the language designers are adding features thoughtlessly, it's Pythonic (except for #3).

There are many cases where the short-circuiting logical OR can be used to your advantage. Here's a simple one from the source code of [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/6b13ecdc85a54fe9e91d192233168c2b188a856a/requests/sessions.py#L240):

```
cookies = request.cookies or {}
```

It's immediately obvious what the outcome of this code should be, as it reads like a sentence. Now that's not to say that the verbose versions aren't readable:

```
cookies = request.cookies if request.cookies else {}
```

And:

```
cookies = {}

if request.cookies:
    cookies = request.cookies
```

But they're redundant. Python uses the same syntax for dictionaries to prevent the same sort of redundancy:

```
d.get('key', 'fallback')
```

Comment: I changed my accepted answer to this one because the question was whether it's 'Pythonic'.

Answer (score 5):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has nothing to do with the way you use your logical operators.

Assuming the motivation for using the logic operators instead of the conditionals is brevity, then it is better accomplished with the ternary operator:

1. `x = a if a else b` instead of `x = a or b`
2. `x = b if a else a` instead of `x = a and b`
3. `x = x if x else y` or just `if not x: x = y` instead of `x = x or y`

But nobody forbids you to use the other versions too. It's all a meter of personal opinion. The motivation behind introduction of the ternary operator was to avoid the error-prone attempts to achieve the same effect using the `and` and `or` operators (see [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)). They also enable fancy stuff in list comprehensions, and a few more things.

They are not introduced to replace complex if statements, but as a *pythonic* ternary operator: `x if condition else y`.

Comment: Actually, I would contest that these short forms are any better than the explicit `if` blocks.

Comment: I definitely think 3. should be `x = x or y` instead of the trinary.

Comment: To me, `x = x if x else y` is more difficult to read than just an if statement.

Comment: @viktorkerkez `if not x: x = y` discouraged by pep8.

Comment: @Scruffy I agree. I just wrote it in one line since the enumeration with SO markdown syntax brake if I add multiline code blocks :)

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced that in all cases, even x = x or y, the ternary is best because: 1) it is explicit. You know what you are getting back, and it's NOT necessarily a boolean, and 2) it's concise.

Comment: @Scruffy: It *really* depends on the context. The ternary operator can't handle cases like `x = a() or b()`, as you'd have to call `a` twice or store the result in an variable. Just use common sense and don't strive to write the most convoluted one-liner possible.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that using logical operators in this way is not Pythonic. Why would they continue to behave this way if people working on the language thought they were not Pythonic? This is also how lisp behaves and it works quite nicely.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: The ternary operator was introduced to solve the abuse of one-liners that tried to emulate it. `a or b` isn't acting like a ternary operator. Short-circuiting logical operators are a part of the language, so why would `a and b` return anything other than a boolean if the result wasn't meant to be used?

Comment: Hmm. The question was about logical operators, not ternary operators. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Note that I *did* see that you mentioned ternary operators, but you also mentioned logical operators. Just not sure why ternary was brought into the mix.

Comment: This is starting to become a religious debate, whose place is not on SO, so I'm deleting all my comments in this thread :) In my answer I explained only that they should not be used as a replacement for ternary operator and that's all I said. The question was clearly stated: **logical operators replacing if statements**, there was no mention of short-circuiting nor "should these operators be avoided".

Comment: @PhillipCloud: I think Viktor read between the lines and he was right. The motivation for using the logic operators instead of the if statements is brevity. In that case it is better accomplished with the ternary. I edited the answer to make this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pep8 covers this, but to me, in your examples, the `if` statements look more readable (especially to people new to Python (and therefore more Pythonic due to "readability counts") than logical operators, which still look more Pythonic than ternary operators.

However, ternary operators are definitely better than `condition and true_value or false_value`, `(false_value, true_value)[condition]` etc. due to being more readable and less likely to break.